# MTensor of MTensor (aka List of List)

Tags: librarylink

In C++ I have a vector of 2D points :

```
typedef std::array<double, 2> Point;
std::vector<Point> samples;
```

Now, I'm in LibraryLink and I'd want to pass a List of 2D points to Mathematica.

{{0.12345,0.98765},{0.53452,0.87512},...}

How I can approach this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now while one can do this with MTensor_setMTensor as I just discovered, one should *NOT* really go for this approach as it is simpler and nicer to get the starting address of your raw data and index from there as one would do with plain C/C++.

```c
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int RandomRealLDBN(  WolframLibraryData libData, 
                                        mint Argc, MArgument* Args, MArgument Res) 
{
    // Error
    int err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    
    // Args
    const mint isamples = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);

    // Setup nb of samples
    const mint nsamples = std::floor(std::sqrt((double)isamples)) *2;
    const mint nrealslots = 2;

    // Tensor to hold nsamples slots of 2 reals
    MTensor oT;
    mint oDims[2];
    oDims[0] = nsamples;
    oDims[1] = nrealslots;
    const mint oRank = 2;
    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, oRank, oDims, &oT);
    if(err) return err;

    // Low-Discrepancy BlueNoise
    std::vector<Point> samples;
    initSamplers();
    ldbnBNOT(nsamples, samples);

    // Setup subtensor to hold sample data
    MTensor iT;
    mint iDims[] = {nrealslots};
    const mint iRank = 1;
    const mint nPos = 1;
    mint pos[1];

    // Yep, MTensor is a 1-based array as in WM
    for(int i=1; i<=nsamples; i++)
    {
        Point s = samples[i-1];

        // allocate a tensor to hold the sample
        err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, iRank, iDims, &iT);
        if(err) return err;

        // fill in the sample data
        mreal *sample = libData->MTensor_getRealData(iT);
        sample[0] = s[0]; //copy sample data
        sample[1] = s[1];

        // update index
        pos[0] = i;

        //insert subtensor in our main tensor list at pos
        err = libData->MTensor_setMTensor(oT, iT, pos, nPos);
        if(err) return err;
    }

    //[....]

    // Get back to WM
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, oT);
    return err;
}
```

The function signature in WM is:

```
RandomRealLDBN = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad[randomRealLDBNLib, 
  "RandomRealLDBN", {Integer}, {Real, 2}]
```

We'll have data back in WM with this layout

> {{0.25, 0.4375}, {0.6875, 0.125}, {0.40625, 0.9375}, {0.8125, 0.625}}

**So as Szabolcs is saying we can go as simple as**

```c
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int RandomRealLDBN(  WolframLibraryData libData, 
                                        mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) 
{
    // Error
    int err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
    
    // Args
    const mint isamples = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);

    // Setup nb of samples
    const mint samplerow = std::floor(std::sqrt((double)isamples));
    const mint nsamples = pow(samplerow,2);
    const mint nrealslots = 2;

    // Tensor to hold nsamples slots of 2 reals
    MTensor oT;
    const mint oDims[2] = {nsamples, nrealslots};
    const mint oRank = 2;
    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, oRank, oDims, &oT);
    if(err) return err;

    // Low-Discrepancy BlueNoise
    std::vector<Point> samples;
    initSamplers();
    ldbnBNOT(samplerow, samples);

    // Get the starting address of the data to be filled in
    mreal *datastartingaddress = libData->MTensor_getRealData(oT);

    // Fill in samples data
    memcpy(datastartingaddress, &samples[0], sizeof(double)*nsamples*nrealslots);

    // Same as above
    /*for(int i=0; i < nsamples; i++){
        Point s = samples[i];
        datastartingaddress[i*nrealslots +0] = s[0];
        datastartingaddress[i*nrealslots +1] = s[1];
    }*/

    //[...]

    // Get back to WM
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, oT);
    return err;
}
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no such thing as an "MTensor of MTensors". You are repeatedly creating a small MTensor (`iT`) and never freeing it. There's a huge memory leak.  Use `getRealData` on `oT` to get a pointer to the underlying storage and fill that in directly.

Answer (score 4):

You are overcomplicating this. There is no such thing as an "MTensor of MTensors" (i.e. an MTensor cannot contain other MTensors), but you don't need it anyway.  A list of 2D points can be represented as an `n` by `2` matrix, i.e. a two-dimensional MTensor.

I would recommend not to use the `MTensor_setXXX` and `MTensor_getXXX` functions. These are very cumbersome to use (you need to construct the position argument) and more importantly: *they are slow*. Function calls are expensive, and if you call a function for each array indexing operation, it will kill performance.

Just get a pointer to the underlying storage with `MTensor_getXXXData` and use that directly. Data is stored in a contiguous memory region in row-major order, i.e. in an `m` by `n` matrix the position of the `i, j` element (zero-based indexing) is `i*n + j`.

---

Note: You can use my LTemplate package to simplify things and get convenient zero-based indexing as `mat(i,j)`.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but I had a stupid bug where I left in the for loop .. i<=nsamples .. ie. the = should have not been there (for 0-based ar).. so I was copying crap to non allocated mem and that was crashing the WM kernel randomly after many executions of the fnc.. and I just thought it wasn't the right way to go after found the MTensor_setMTensor :/

Comment: However as I added at the end of my answer why we have to copy mem if we could just let it point to the MTensor data ? It's crashing the kernel instantly instead ! Maybe I should open another question just for that.

Comment: @MaxTarpini The internals of MTensor are not accessible. You wrote `oT->data`, but I assume this is just "hypothetical code". There is no information in the header files about what's in an MTensor. Furthermore, the storage is allocated and deallocated by Mathematica. Even if you knew the internals, swapping out a pointer like that would likely lead to a crash eventually.

Comment: @MaxTarpini You don't have to copy memory: you can create an MTensor, get a pointer to its storage, then generate the data directly in to that space. If your existing functions can't place data into arbitrary memory, and _must_ return their result through an `std::vector`, then this is not possible and you must copy.

Comment: @MaxTarpini OK, I see you got that `struct` from `WolframCompileLibrary.h`. If you look at it in different versions of Mathematica you will see an entirely different structure. This is the first issue. Second, you don't know what Mathematica will do with whatever you put in there. It is likely to call `free` or maybe an entirely different deallocation function on it. Just don't do it.

Comment: Yeah no need for that. In a more delicate situation I'd start directly from MTensor. Btw the last code I added I see it hurts the eyes but that's just correct because of this..  typedef struct st_MDataArray *MTensor; Thanks for the detailed comments and answer ! Btw, how it works.. you prefer I flag your answer as winwin or mine that has the code examples ?

Comment: @MaxTarpini I don't care about reputation score or green checkmarks so you don't have to accept this. Just please make sure you don't suggest to people to use `setMTensor`. Do check out my [LTemplate](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate) package. It's a bit quirky but it makes big projects easier.

Comment: Ok, great. I also removed the question about the data pointer as it's already highlighted here with your comments. Will try LTemplate ! Thanks for all.